# Extra padding at top and bottom in CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, padding, android-cardview

I'm using to recyclerview to display a list a images from a web service. I'm trying to display images in ImageView within CardView widget.Everything is working fine. All the images and lists are displaying properly. but when i try to run on Kitkat 4.4.4 its showing extra(Large) padding at top and bottom of image within the Cardview. I'm using ImageView only no text nothing.

Check the attached image.

on 4.4.4
[image]

on Lollipop
[image]
I've tried almost everything that i've found on SO so far. 
any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

XML code for Cardview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_half">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/offwhite"
    android:id="@+id/cardlayout_malls"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_half"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_half">-->
    <!-- Thumbnail Image -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bannerImageView"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show me your xml file

Comment: are you using match_parent in the adapter's XML file, if yes then change it to wrap_content

Comment: please post the xml code

Comment: @RakshitNawani i'm using wrap_content for height and match_parent for width

Comment: @deejay : Please share your XML code then for better understanding

Comment: this XML setting is working fine for Lollipop and upper versions but not on pre-lollipop

Comment: Try adding this card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false" or CardView.setMaxCardElevation(0) in your XML or code and then do let me know if it worked for you

Comment: okay thanks.. I'll try and let you know..

Comment: still same.. large paddings..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this way

```
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
```

**OR**

in imageview you can use  add this in your imageview

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/bannerImageView"/>
```

Comment: `no resources found for adjustedviewbound`.. can you please be more specific?

Comment: @deejay check now

Comment: thanks @Aditya its worked.. now its not showing any padding but the elevation and shadow effect is also gone.. can you please guide me here?

Comment: I know about using `<view/> ` to make the shadow just under the cardview but it doesn't seems to be a neat method.

Answer (score 0):

add`card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"`
Extra padding is because of those tiny round corners which, need to be disabled. Basically that is not a flaw rather a Design constraint!

Comment: tried it .. its removing rounded corners on 5.0  and up but still same on 4.4.4